# How an AP blocks Admin Page through Wi-Fi connection?

Tags: web-application, wifi, access-control, router

Some home routers (AP) have the ability to block connections to the admin page if it's being accessed through a Wi-Fi connection. In order to login to the admin page you need to get a cable and connect to the network.

- How does the web page/service (80 or 443) knows this?
- How secure (easy to circumvent) is it?

Is it trough the hardware, firmware or software? Even tho it looks kind of obvious because the router serves both (Wi-Fi and web admin page) I can't get my head around it because of the OSI layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firewalls can look across layers. Assume you're on a Linux system where `eth0` is your LAN and `wlan0` is your WLAN, and they're both bridged into `br0`. The following iptables rule would then do it:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -i br0 -m physdev --physdev-in wlan0 -j DROP
```